# null is not an object ( evaluating 'RNGestureHandlerModule.Direction')

Tags: android

An issue in React native Version `0.60`

> ->null is not an object ( evaluating 'RNGestureHandlerModule.Direction')

I'm using react-native-gesture-handler within react-navigation and run react-native run-android and getting this errornull is not an object

> ( evaluating 'RNGestureHandlerModule.Direction')

How to solve it, please? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? This solved my problem

1. Right Click Libraries "Add Files to Project"
2. /node_modules/react-native-gesture-handlers/ios/RNGestureHandler.xcodeproj
3. Go to build phases and add libRNGestureHandler.a
4. run the app then and try

Answer (score 0):

this I how It got it working

delete the app from the simulator

```
 run on terminal -> react-native link
```

Goto ios folder

```
 run on terminal -> pod install
```